# AWS IAM - Allow All actions except a few actions on IAM side

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an AWS SSO permission set where I need to allow to do all the actions on all the resources but except a few actions on a few IAM roles.(I have a few roles where I dont want other to modify anything)

I have added this permission,  but still getting errors of explicit deny.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePermissionsBoundary",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePermissionsBoundary"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/AWSReservedSSO_SK-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/AWSServiceRole*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Error:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_test-Limit_xxxxx/user@domain.com is not authorized to perform: iam:GetAccountSummary on resource: * with an explicit deny
```

Comment: Have you checked Service Control Polices (SCP) applied to the account?

Comment: no service control policies

Comment: And when do you get that 'explicit deny' message (in which part of web console)?

Comment: Yes, its from the console.

Comment: In which part? (in which section/button do you get that error)

Comment: All the places, IAM home page, Users(ListUser denied), Roles (List roles denied)